# Python Script Fix for 2.8 Rigify

Tags: python, rigify

How could I write a script to find all bones that are using a custom shape and enable wire-frame on them, so I don't have to do it manually for like 100+ bones. I'm not that good with Python.

I had to figure it out on my own. So for the benefit of all ,
here's the code to automate the process

That is literally two lines, just copy this into Blender's text editor and hit *Run Script* and it will make your IK endpoints visible. You may need to make all armature layers visible.

*NOTE:* This will set *ALL* bones to wire-frame, but let me know in the comments in anyone needs to make it more specific.

```
import bpy

for bns in bpy.context.object.data.bones: 
        bns.show_wire = True
```

Comment: @RocketFriday Hello and welcome. Thanks for posting your findings. The spirit of this site is to learn from each other, the way your question was phrased does read like a job assignment not a intention of learning. Answering your own question however is totally acceptable and encouraged, but you should do so in the answer section bellow, don't edit it in as part of the question.